# Function to find if a date exists and if so print that row AND the next 6 rows of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I have this handy function that can do the first part of finding the row and returning the data required, but what I need is it to also return the next 6 rows after.

This is what I currently have:

```
def weekoforders(date):
    cond=df1['date'].isin([pd.to_datetime(date)])
    if cond.any():
        return df1.loc[cond,['date','orders']]
    return 'No'


weekoforders('2020-02-02')

      date      orders
101 2020-02-02  11121
```

What I need is an output like so:

```
         date     orders
101      2020-02-02 1012
102      2020-02-03 1023
103      2020-02-04 1034
104      2020-02-05 1045
105      2020-02-06 1545
106      2020-02-07 5455
107      2020-02-08 9874
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately, you just get the one row outputted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out eventually. I made the date column the index and used the following:

````
def one(date):
    end_date = pd.to_datetime(date) + pd.DateOffset(days=6)
    return df1.loc[date:end_date]
one('2020-05-05')  ```
````